# Hankel transform of shifted circle, or 2-D Fourier transform of a circle in a plane

Tags: fourier-transform, polar-coordinates

I want to compute the 2D Fourier transform of the function $circ(\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2})$. Obviously, this is a circle centered at $(a,b)$ and with radius 1, because of the $circ$ function.

How do I compute the Hankel transform of this, since the function is radially symmetric.

I believe that the first step is convert the equation $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=1$ to polar coordinates, with the parametrization $x=cos\theta+a$, $y=sin\theta+b$, so you get the familiar trigonometric identity. However I don't understand what to do now, since it seems like the shift in location has disappeared and therefore cannot be reflected in the Hankel transform.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: The Fourier transform of a circ is a jinc.  So just apply the shift theorem.

Comment: @NicNic8 I'm a bit confused about the validity of the shift theorem in this case. I 'intuitively' think that the answer is just as you said - the Jinc with a factor of $e^{-2\pi j (a\nu_{x}+b\nu_{y})}$ ahead of it, but I'm trying to reason why.

Comment: A shift in one domain is multiplication by a complex exponential in the other.  It’s that simple.  You can see a proof here:  https://nicholasdwork.com/teaching/1706ee102a/lectures/lecture06.pdf